# Flutter: Check if actually connected to the internet (web, ...)

Tags: flutter, web, connection

How can I check if the app is connected to the internet, especially on web. `InternetAddress.lookup` is not supported on web and `http.get` has quite some overhead, because it fetches the entire webpage.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this package to check if you are connected to internet or not :

https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_checker